# Why FLAIR does't recognize the entire location name of simple sentence?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, named-entity-recognition, flair

I'm tying to to detect simple location with NER algorithm, and I'm getting semi-correct results:

```
from flair.data   import Sentence
from flair.models import SequenceTagger

tagger   = SequenceTagger.load('ner')
text     = 'Jackson leaves at north Carolina'
sentence = Sentence(text)

tagger.predict(sentence)
for entity in sentence.get_spans('ner'):
    print(entity)
```

Output:

```
Span [1]: "Jackson"   [− Labels: PER (0.9996)]
Span [5]: "Carolina"   [− Labels: LOC (0.7363)]
```

I was expecting to receive `"north Carolina"`.

1. Can FLAIR detect full location description? What do we need for it?
2. Is there any NER algorithm that cat detect full location description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FLAIR CAN detect full location description. The reason for your issue is that the 'north' is not capitalized.

If you run

```py
from flair.data   import Sentence
from flair.models import SequenceTagger

tagger   = SequenceTagger.load('ner')
text     = 'Jackson leaves at North Carolina'
sentence = Sentence(text)

tagger.predict(sentence)
for entity in sentence.get_spans('ner'):
    print(entity)
```

You'll get

```
Span[0:1]: "Jackson" → PER (0.9997)
Span[3:5]: "North Carolina" → LOC (0.9246)
```